# Cambiar forma de figura rectangular a una personalizada

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

He desarrollado una página en HTML con algunas animaciones en CSS y JavaScript. Lo que pretendo es cambiar la forma de la figura rectangular a una personalizada, o podría usar una imagen también.

La siguiente imagen sería la animación que desarrollé actualmente: a medida que el % varía de 0 a 100% se va llenando el contenedor de azul (live data)

[image: Animacion desarrollada]

Lo que se pretende cambiar es la forma del contenedor como una de esta por ejemplo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualización:

Acabo de actualizar mi objetivo, ya tengo el código, lo que ahora pretendo hacer es cambiar "height" de un pseudo elemento en css con una variable definida en javascript.

el pseudo elemento seria `box::before`, "`height`"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });

  let counter = 0;


  setInterval(function() {

    counter++;

    $('.box::before').css({
      "height": counter
    });

  }, 1000);


})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 120px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00ff3c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>

  <div class="box"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Se puede hacer con css y javascript pero, necesitamos ver tu código para encontrar algún problema y solucionar. Sin código es como que pides que se te haga la tarea

Comment: Como dice Narciso necesitaríamos ver tu código. De todas formas, con la propiedad `border-radius` al 50% puedes hacer lo que creo que buscas. Otra opción, si lo que buscas es algo de interactividad es tirar de las transformaciones CSS. Te dejo la página de w3schools donde te lo explica...
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la información, si pueden orientarme mil gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que no puedes seleccionar el `::before` the la clase `.box` porqué es un pseudo-selector, pero puedes conseguir el mismo resultado con un `div` (o algún otro elemento) anidado en el `div.box`, como `div.fill` del ejemplo.

Los estilos que aplicaban para el `.box::before` son los mismos para el `.fill` a excepción de `content`. Y en el script sólo agregué una condición para detener el `interval`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let counter = 100
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  
    // detener función cuando se haya llenado por completo
    if ($('.box .fill').height() === $('.box').height()) 
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    
    $('.box .fill').css('height', counter++)
    
  }, 200)
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 120px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fill {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00ff3c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-value="100">
  <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
```